# How to move contents of folder into its directory only if it's the only thing in the current directory?

Tags: windows

I have a bunch of folders arranged in such a way:
Folder 1
--Folder 1 A
---------*files
Folder 2<---------Level 1
--Folder 2 A<------------Level 2
--------*files
I'd like to extract all the files from each level 2 folder into the level 1 folder only if the level 2 folder is the only file/folder in its level 1 folder.

Answer (score 0):

This PowerShell should do it.

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory |  
 ?{((Get-ChildItem $_.Fullname -Directory).Count -eq 1) -and
   ((Get-ChildItem $_.Fullname).Count -eq 1) } |
 Foreach{
    $files = Get-ChildItem $_.Fullname -file -recurse
    move-item $files.FullName $_.Fullname
}
```